# How to estimate the parameters of a model using NLS (or other) regression?

Tags: stata, nls

I am trying to estimate the parameters of a theoretical model using a NLS (non linear least square) regression in Stata.The parameters are: alpha (sensitivity to the assets' returns of participants in our experiment), beta (sensitivity to risk) and gamma (sensitivity to the environment).

The two problems I encountered:

(1) The alpha parameter of my model cannot be estimated by the NLS regression (see screenshot #1 below).

(2) In the .do file, all variables are automatically marked blue except the beta variable which remains grayed out. I don't know the reason for this and I don't know if this  is responsible for the problem (1). See screenshot #2 below.

Could you help me to estimate the three parameters of this model? Indeed, I have never worked with NLS regressions.

[Screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNa8Q.png)

[Screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvnUP.png)

Comment: We need a reproducible example. What is the point of declaring as many clusters as there are data points?

Comment: For (2), `alpha` and `gamma` are not highlighted because they are "variables". They are highlighted because they are recognized commands/keywords in Stata (though `gamma` has long been deprecated I believe) whereas `beta` is not.

Comment: @NickCox I declared clusters on the participants' code because they participate in 3 consecutive rounds. We have 3 data for each participant.

Comment: @JR96 I tried with other keywords (omega, lamda) and these words are still not highlighted in blue.

Do you have any other ideas? 

Thank you.

Comment: But your first screenshot is showing as many clusters as observations used.

Comment: Omega and lamda are not keywords. The moral of the story is .do files do not have the capability to recognize variable names in memory; the highlighting you see is coincidence.